# read web.config value is aspx file in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-config

I am working on an ASP.NEt application. In one of the ASPX page, in the  tag, in a function, I need to use a value from the Web.config file. I tried using couple of options online, but it not working.

Is it a good idea to read web.config value like this? If not, then is there a better way to do it?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

The Web.config file should never be read by anything that is not part of your web application. If you need a value out of it there are classes in `System.Web.Configuration` or `System.Configuration` that do exactly [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.appsettings.aspx). You can then use the read value and embed it in the page itself.

Comment: I agree, but when I use the System.Configuration in the Javascript function on ASPX page, its not working:"For example: <%ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteRootURL"]%>"

Comment: You'll need to use it in the `Page_Load` handler in the code behind, assigning the value to a property you can then databind in the page itself.